# Inconsistent rep requirement for editing tag wikis

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, tag-wiki, privileges

The [Stack Overflow privileges list](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges) says you need [1500 reputation to edit tag wikis](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit-tag-wiki), but the bottom of each tag info page says:

> To edit this wiki, you must have a total score of 100 on non-community-wiki answers in this tag (you currently have X), and at least 2000 reputation.

Is it 1500 or 2000? I always thought it was the latter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's 1500; we changed it a few days ago to encourage contribution and have a privilege that unlocks at 1500.

I updated the pages.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me... :( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66968/how-do-i-edit-the-tag-wiki

Comment: Me neither, seems you have to have a bronze badge for the tag in question. Seems this should be checked or explained after the privilege is awarded IMHO.

Comment: @java good call; I updated the help page to indicate that.

Comment: Thank, you. That will be helpful.